# map operator does not return the correct results

Tags: angular, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have been struggling with the following issue for quite some time now.

```
...

export interface HotelRoomType {
  foo: string;
  boo: number;
  rplans: Array<RatePlan>
}

export interface RatePlan {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: boolean;
  prop3: number 
}

doc1: HotelRoomType;
doc2: HotelRoomType;
doc3: HotelRoomType;

ratePlansArr$: Observable<RatePlan[]>;
...
```

doc1, doc2 and doc3 are firestore documents of a

```
/Company/CompanyId/Room_Types
```

sub-collection.

The first document is the following

```
doc1 = {
  foo: 'a',
  boo: 1,
  rplans: [
    {
      prop1: 'xxx',
      prop2: true,
      prop3: 512.50
    },
    { 
      prop1: 'yyy',
      prop2: false,
      prop3: 101  
    }
  ]
}
```

the second one:

```
doc2 = {
  foo: 'b',
  boo: 9,
  rplans: [
    {
      prop1: 'ooo',
      prop2: false,
      prop3: 90
    },
    { 
      prop1: 'mmm',
      prop2: false,
      prop3: 120.80  
    },
    { 
      prop1: 'nnn',
      prop2: true,
      prop3: 80  
    },
  ]
}
```

and a third one following the same pattern

The following method, (using AngularFire) returns an observable of RatePlan Array

```
public getAllRatePlansForCompany(companyId: string): Observable<RatePlan[]> {
    return this._fsSrvc.colWithIds$<RatePlan[]>('Company/' + companyId + '/Room_Types/')
      .pipe(
        map((res, idx) => res = res[idx].Rate_plans)
      );
  }
```

The method is called like this:

```
this.ratePlansArr$ = this.inventoryService.getAllRatePlansForCompany(this.company.id);
this.ratePlansArr$.subscribe();
```

However, when executed, it only returns the rplans of the first document (doc1).

How shall it be modified to return an Array containing the rplans of all 3 documents ?

Thank you

Comment: What kind of rxjs are you using? I dont know what bi consumer map clousure looks alike.

Comment: Dont you want to use flatMap ?

Comment: I m using the latest (6.4.0) version or rxjs

Answer (score 1):

Try `flatMap`

`flatMap((doc) => doc.rplans)`. That would idealy make 1d array from array of arrays.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I m still only getting the items of the first doc's array, but as individual objects, not as an array.

Comment: That would mean you got only 1 results resulted form firebase. Add `tap(console.log)` before map to see how many (and what kind of) elements you actually get.

Comment: Nope, I was getting all individual docs from firestore, but not in an array; each document as a single object. I found a workaround as below, but i m sure it can be done in a different way, purely using rxjs operators: ``` this.roomsService.getAllHotelRoomTypesForCompany(this.company.id)
      .pipe(
        tap(hrts => {
          hrts.forEach(hrt => {
            this.allRatePlans = this.allRatePlans.concat(hrt.Rate_plans);
          });
          console.log(this.allRatePlans);
        }),
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe();```

Comment: If it is not collection, how do you want to get 3 docs using 1 call?

Answer (score 0):

AS I see you call for data only once here:

```
 this.ratePlansArr$ = this.inventoryService.getAllRatePlansForCompany(this.company.id);
```

To get 3 results you should call it thrice:

```
const conpanyIds = [1,2,3];
const arrayOfObservables = conpanyIds.map(id => this.inventoryService.getAllRatePlansForCompany(id))

this.ratePlansArr$ = forkJoin(arrayOfObservables).pipe(
  (arrayOfresults) => arrayOfresults.rplans
)

this.ratePlansArr$.subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: You can learn more in my video course: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-rxjs-web-development-video